# How to hide a published Taxonomy page unless you're an authorized user?

Tags: 7, views

I have a link on my website, I'm currently using Taxonomy Access Control Lite, I have a Taxonomy vocab "Manitoba" and I would like to not let the contents of this page be seen unless the user logged in has the permission role to view it.

How would I go about hiding contents from a page belonging to a taxonomy and all the sub-pages that entail?

Answer (score 0):

To get tac_lite to work covering your question on a vanilla Drupal 7, one has to do the following:

1. Enable at least one tac_lite permissions scheme for the target vocabulary, in your case, "Manitoba" (scrsht.1)
2. Configure the scheme to allow 'viewing' for authenticated users (scrsht.2)
3. Create a node, e.g. an article and assign a term to it. Authenticated users should be able to see it (scrsht.3), anonymous not (scrsht.4).

Hope that helps!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize there was a config page for the module. One question I have is if there is a message to replace the hidden content if the user is not authorized?

Comment: Hi there, yes, there is that config page, had to dig around some myself to find it. If this worked for you, you should set the answer to accepted. And regarding the follow-up question, you should open a new question. Cheers